# Access an array item that is an anonymous hash in Template Toolkit in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, template-toolkit

I have this piece of code as part of a foreach loop in my controller:

```
my $gr = My::Model::Group->new(id => $gra->gr_id);
$gra = My::Model::Group::Admin->new(id => $gra->id);
push(@$groups, {$gr => $gra});
```

In @$groups array I want to store anonymous hashes where the key element is the group object and the value element is the admin of that group object. Then in the template I want to show the list of different groups that the admin can log in, for that I have this code:

```
[%- FOREACH  gr IN groups -%]
  <li><input type="radio" name="group" value="[% gr.id %]">[% gr.name %]</input></li>
[%- END -%]
```

I know that the p IN partners is not right but is to show you what I want to achieve. Any suggestions on the template code?

Comment: The `FOREACH item IN list` is correct. But you want to regroup them, right? This is like a pivot in Excel. You have something like `{ 1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar', 3 => 'foo' }` and you want to show that user `foo` has `1, 3` and `bar` has `2`. Did I understand?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You got it absolutely correct

Comment: Is there more than one admin? I don't understand the expected output yet.

Comment: The admin is going to be the same, I mean, that it's going to be the same admin for several groups. but I want to capture the groups and the admin in hash form. Later I will do something more with the admin but not for now. So now the desire output it would be the group name and id.

Comment: So you want to group by admin? That is logic that really shouldn't go into the template. But it's possible.

Comment: Correct, so what would you suggest?

Comment: I am struggling with the TT syntax right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[duskwuff already explains in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43754461/1331451) that you can't use objects as hash keys as they get serialized and you'll lose the object-ness. My answer builds on that.

Let's say you have an array of arrays instead, where each inner array holds a pair of objects. I've created Moo classes to illustrate.

```
package My::Model::Group;
use Moo;
has [qw/id name/] => ( is => 'ro' );

package My::Model::Group::Admin;
use Moo;
has [qw/id name/] => ( is => 'ro' );

package main;

my $groups = [
    [
        My::Model::Group->new( id => 1, name => 'group1' ) =>
            My::Model::Group::Admin->new( id => 1, name => 'foo' )
    ],
    [
        My::Model::Group->new( id => 2, name => 'group2' ) =>
            My::Model::Group::Admin->new( id => 1, name => 'foo' )
    ],
    [
        My::Model::Group->new( id => 3, name => 'group3' ) =>
            My::Model::Group::Admin->new( id => 1, name => 'bar' )
    ],
    [
        My::Model::Group->new( id => 4, name => 'group4' ) =>
            My::Model::Group::Admin->new( id => 1, name => 'foo' )
    ],
];
```

There are four pairs. Two admins, four groups. Three of the groups belong to the *foo* admin, and one to *bar*. Now let's look at the template.

```
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process( \*DATA, { groups => $groups }, \my $output )
   or die $tt->error;

print $output;
__DATA__
[%- FOREACH item IN groups -%]
    [%- DEFAULT by_admin.${item.1.name} = [] -%]
    [%- by_admin.${item.1.name}.push(item.0) -%]
[%- END -%]

[%- FOREACH admin IN by_admin.keys.sort -%]
    [%- FOREACH group IN by_admin.$admin -%]
        [%- admin %] -> [% group.id %]

    [%- END -%]
[%- END -%]
```

The relevant part obviously is the `DATA` section. We need to reorganize the array data structure into a hash that has the admins, and then each group sorted into one of the admin slots.

We don't need to create the `by_admin` variable. It will be created globally implicitly. But we do need to set a default value for `$by_admin->{$item[0]->name}` (I'm using Perl syntax now, to make it easier to understand). It seems like Template Toolkit does not know [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification), and [the `DEFAULT` keyword](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_DEFAULT) is similar to the [`//=` assignment operator in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators).

We can then [`push`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#method_unshift_item_push) the first element of `item` into the array ref we just created (if it didn't exist yet) inside the hash ref element with the key `item.1.name` inside `by_name`.

Once we're done preparing, the rest is just a simple loop. We iterate the [`sort`ed](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_sort_nsort) [`keys`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_keys) of `by_admin`, and then iterate the array ref that's behind that key.

Here's the output:

```
bar -> 3
foo -> 1
foo -> 2
foo -> 4
```

It would make sense to do the preprocessing not in a template, but in your controller instead. As normal Perl code it should be easier to read.

```
my %by_admin;
for my $group (@$groups) {
    push @{ $by_admin{ $group->[1]{name} } }, $group->[0];
}
```

---

Note that I have omitted `use strict` and `use warnings` for brevity.

Comment: with that snippet of code I got it. Thanks a lot! You guys made my day

Comment: @Albert the really important part is the `DEFAULT`. That's what took me a while to figure out.

Comment: As you mentioned, this is best done in Perl (not TT), so I added the Perl code to do it.

Comment: Thank you @ikegami.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to rework your code significantly to make this possible.

Keys in Perl hashes are *strings*, not scalars. Using anything that isn't a string as a key in a hash (e.g, `$gr` in the expression `{ $gr => $gra }` will cause it to be stringified, just as if you had interpolated it into a string or printed it. Unless you have explicitly overloaded the `""` operator on the `My::Model::Group` object, the key will end up being stored as a literal string along the lines of:

```
"My::Model::Group=HASH(0x1234567890)"
```

This string cannot be converted back to the original object -- in fact, the original object was probably garbage-collected as soon as it went out of scope, so it no longer exists at all.

Consider storing the pair as an array reference instead, e.g.

```
push @$groups, [$gr, $gra];
```

Comment: ok, but then how I an access to the id in $gr in the template?